# Unable to Launch Tor Browser

Tags: package-management, software-installation, tor

I'm unable to launch the Tor Browser.  I downloaded it following the instructions on this page: [How to Install Tor Browser on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tor-browser-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I've tried clicking on both icons--to no effect.  And when I try to launch it from the terminal, I get this error:

```
Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Comment: On ' SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED' update gpg to 2.2.17 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this package with this command:

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:

SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED!

Error Code: GENERIC_VERIFY_FAIL

You might be under attack, there might be a network problem, or you may be missing a recently added Tor Browser verification key.
Click Start to refresh the keyring and try again.  If the message persists report he above error code here:
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues

Comment: Try this command gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu

Comment: gpg: keyserver refresh failed: No data

Comment: Try again with sudo gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu, if it still dont work you can see this thread https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/263